# How to loop through URLs based on variable, such as date?

Tags: python, loops, request

This is an example of a URL, I want to use to scrape. The URL changes based on the date:

https://betfair-data-supplier-prod.herokuapp.com/api/daily_racing_results?date=2020-01-01

I want to scrape data from the 1st of January to the 30th of June. How would I create a for loop to do this.

For example:

```
for day and month in URL:
    request = requests.get(f'https://betfair-data-supplier-prod.herokuapp.com/api/daily_racing_results?date=2020-{month}-{day})
```

Comment: you can use `pandas.date_range`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set start date and end date. Then loop through them by increment by one day. then append the current date of iteration to the date parameter of your query:

```
import datetime
import requests

start_date = datetime.date(2019, 12, 31)
end_date = datetime.date(2020, 6, 30)

day_count = (end_date - start_date).days

date = start_date
for i in range(day_count):
    date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    request = requests.get('https://betfair-data-supplier-prod.herokuapp.com/api/daily_racing_results?date=' + str(date))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare dates so increment by one day from the beginning of the time period

```
Import datetime as dt
delta = dt.timedelta(days=1)
i = dt.date(2020, 1, 1)
ed = dt.date(2020, 6, 30)
while i<=ed:
    i += delta
    print(f'this/day/{i}')
```

produces

```
this/day/2020-01-01
this/day/2020-07-02
this/day/2020-07-03
...
this/day/2020-06-29
this/day/2020-06-30
```